I'm writing a children's book and want to use Leonardo.ai to create all the characters in the same illustration style. Is that possible?
It seems that if I include the seed of the style I like, that's what creates consistency.  Is that correct and complete? I'm a n00b, so if there's anything else you can suggest, I'd sure appreciate it.

I'm not knowledgeable enough to give specifics, but look into how LoRA can help with "character specialization". Mastering Low-Rank Adaptation (LoRA): Enhancing Large Language Models for Efficient Adaptation
